# How to optimize this Delete Query

Tags: sql, db2, sql-delete, sqlperformance

Table Structure

- Global_Record      1..* Division_Record
- Division_Record 1..*
  Branch_Record
- Branch_Record   1..* Branch_Response_Record
- Branch_Response_Record 1..* Product_Response_Record
- Global_Record  1..* Product_Record
- Product_Record 1..*  Product_Response_Record

All primary keys are Integer auto increment column.

Here I have to delete records in Branch_Response belongs to a Global_Record
if no data exists for that in Product_Response. ( Product_Response have a foreign key relation with Branch_Response_Record )

Sample query I have written with my very basic SQL knowledge is here,
All columns used in Query have index , so I believe performance should be fine.

However I want to know if I can replace IN with EXISTS to improve performance ? or any other option ?

```
DELETE FROM Branch_Response_Record
  WHERE Branch_Record_id IN
    ( 
     SELECT BR.Branch_Record_id 
        FROM Branch_Record BR
          INNER JOIN Division_Record DR 
             ON BR.Branch_Record_id = DR.Branch_Record_id
          INNER JOIN Global_Record GR 
             ON DR.Global_Record_id = CR. Global_Record_id
        WHERE Global_Record_id = 123 
    ) 
    AND NOT IN 
    ( 
      SELECT DISTINCT Branch_Response_Id 
        FROM Product_Response_Record 
          WHERE Branch_Response_Record_id IN
         ( 
           SELECT DISTINCT Branch_response_id 
             FROM Product_Response_Record 
               WHERE Product_id IN
               ( 
                 SELECT PRR.Product_Id 
                  FROM Product_Response_Record PRR
                     INNER JOIN product_Record PR 
                        ON PRR.Product_Id = PR.Product_Id 
                 WHERE Global_Record_id = 123
               )
         ) 
     )
```

I didn't give any sample data as mostly keys only involved in the query and if I am wrong please let me know, I will add some data too :)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, there is only so much query optimization that can be done without knowing your data.  However:

1. The second subquery (the `and not in` part) seems wrong: you appear to be selecting `branch_response_id` and comparing it to `branch_record_id`.
2. The second subquery will probably be a lot more efficient if you use `inner join` in place of your nested `in` clauses.
3. A possible way to optimise is to put all the `branch_response_id`s you want to delete into a session table, then have a simple delete query using that information.